# How to encrypt parameters of URL in ASP.NET MVC with Routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a very specific problem, I want to encrypt and decrypt my URL parameters in ASP.net MVC.

If my current url is like this :

```
http:/mywebsite/controler/Action/ParameterValue1/ParameterValue2/ParameterVale3
```

I want to appear it on user browser as:

```
http:/mywebsite/controler/Action/EncryptedParameterValue1/EncryptedParameterValue2
/EncryptedParameterValue3
```

With the help of Routes table.

Answer (score 0):

Use hashing to encrypt/decrypt value.

More info at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38796/Simple-Encrypt-and-Decrypt-Technique-and-Computing

Comment: Hi thanks for showing interset in qusetion... but i am looking for encryption of URL Parameter in MVC by the help of route.